# In my code an Error:(47, 12) error: invalid method declaration; return type required is present

Tags: java, android

> Error:(47, 12) error: invalid method declaration; return type required

`CommunicationHandler` class is my Singleton Class through which I want to access my api present in the vmware:

```
public class CommunicationHandler {

    private CommunicationHandler instance;

    public CommunicationHandler() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new CommunicationHandler();
        }

        return;
    }

    private ApiConnection connection;

    public boolean connect(String ip, String un, String pw) {

        try {
            connection = connect(ip);
            connection.login(un, pw);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.toString();
        }

        return true;
    }

    private ApiConnection connect(String ip) {
        return null;
    }

    public Execute(String command) throws MikrotikApiException {
        connection.execute(command);
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1241241 Where is the bug ?Can you please Help me debug it?

Comment: did i forget to add void in the Execute() method?